# What happens if the washing machine discharge hose is too far down the stand pipe?

Tags: appliances, washing-machine, washer

I never knew you shouldn't insert more than 5" of the hose down the stand pipe.
Installed mine about a year ago, and I believe I had at least 12" down the pipe. Haven't seen any problem so far. Can anything bad happen if I leave that much hose down the stand pipe? (the pipe is 30" from the floor)

Answer (score 3):

There will always be a small amount of water that remains in the bottom of your washer. When the pump stops the water just past the pump to the top of the washer will fall back down. If your drain hose is inserted too far down the stand pipe, with the right drain configuration, you could siphon water from the drain pipes into your washer when your washer pump stops. The fact that you haven't had any problems is good but it wouldn't hurt to adjust it to 5" and insure there is an air gap between the hose and stand pipe.

Comment: The hose is too long, can I cut it where I circled: https://ibb.co/kg5xDsk

Comment: @Madz  Yes, provided that there's still an air gap around the inserted hose. It can't be a snug fit.